# Xcode display error ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE when distribute app to app store

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to distribute app (Ionic Capacitor) on Xcode but when I fiinish archrive the app and start distribute, It show `ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE`

```
App record creation error
App record creation failed due to an invalid attribute. Request failed with error code "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE", and reason "The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used The Bundle ID you entered has already been used."
```

[image]

My question is what should I do to fix this? This project I'm not create app on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ but my customer created it and send cert file to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new App on AppStoreConnect

Go to AppStoreConnect, Apps, and create the app manually with the bundle ID you set in your Xcode project.

Then rebuild app and upload.

Comment: I got this error after creating the app in the App Store and trying to distribute.  I created a new appID, app, etc.  Updated Xcode, info.plist, etc... tried to distribute and still get the same thing.  No solution yet.  Any other ideas?